# Fetching data using relationships in coreData swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationships

[CoreData Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqooB.png)

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext:context) as NSManagedObject
```

Above CoreData Model image contains my data model.

I am not able to access time using newUser i.e; newUser.time is giving me an error "Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'time'"

Comment: Have you created class of an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an NSManagedObject subclass (in Editor menu or manually). Then, you can use the following code (Employee being your subclass)

```
let entityDesc =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)!

let entity = Employee(entity: entityDesc, insertIntoManagedObjectContext : managedContext)
```

To access all your fields. Creating a subclass is not mandatory though, you can always use your NSManagedObject as a dictionary and do

```
if let time = newUser.valueForKey("time") as? NSDate {
   //use date here
}
```

However it is ugly.